# text=open('nametext.txt').read() didn't read all

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a txt file to be read by python. But, somehow python only read a little part of it. Is it possible? How can I make python to fully read the text?

P.S.: My txt file contains this
[My txt file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7zN8QD6sy0CUEg4VWFodDIwQTg/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: That doesn't look like a text file.

Comment: Yeah, I encrypt it. But when I tried to decrypt it, only some parts of it were decrypted.

Comment: Try opening it with `open(filename, 'rb')` in binary mode.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check out [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and thoroughly read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help) - in particular, ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @user379677 Yes, your question doesn't have nearly enough information to be considered on-topic for this site. If you read the pages I linked, you would see exactly what your question lacks. Your question title isn't a question, you don't have any code in the body of your question, you didn't provide the minimal, complete verifiable example, and you linked an external file. Just read those pages, then revise your question based on your findings, and then I'm sure people will be happy to help. It's not arbitrary - we literally can't help you with the information you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:
`text=open('nametext.txt').readlines()`